# What is the age gap between Bruce Wayne and Tim Drake?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, age

I'm trying to debunk a theory and this is a key point to my argument. I just need a reliable source to reference and an answer to my question. The most recent DC canon would be appreciated if it can be found. Also I would prefer references to comics over animated series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to debunk MatPat's theory? :D

Anyways I looked through my collection and only reasonable source I found was New 52 Batman Vol 6 - Graveyard Shift. There's a story called Tomorrow depicting lives of Dick, Jason, Barbara and Tim at the start of Batman's career five years prior to start of the New 52. Tim is on high school and from what I understood, he was so clever he actually was able to pass the test to finish the high school prematurely.

At this point, Batman was 25 (assuming MatPat had this right) and I don't know about America, but I personally finished high school in the age of 19. If Tim was smart enough, he could do it anytime between age of 15 and age of 19, leaving him 10-6 years younger than Batman.

There are some issues with DC Rebirth and Tim Drake being a time paradox since Doctor Manhattan stole 10 years from everybody, but I assume that only affects relationship of Tim and Bruce and not affecting the age gap between the two.

Anyways, if you are really trying to debunk MatPat's theory, bear in mind he's talking DCEU here, so the comics timeline does not apply.

Comment: doomista - Batman was 25?  Shouldn't Batman be about 100 years old in 2017?  Of course i hear that comic books have floating timelines and reset from time to time.

Comment: Yeah, comics are really messed up on this one. Simply put the original Batman (and other superheroes) are from alternate dimensions and then there were also retcons which basically make old canon obsolete by replacing it with a new one. That way, writers can do stories about the same time slot over and over again...

Comment: Finish high school any time between 15-19? I know people who finished at 13. Given how exaggerated genius tends to be in comics, Tim could have graduated high school at 10 or 8 or even 5 (not that all of these ages haven't been seen in the real world, too).

Comment: Yeah I am trying to debunk MatPat's theory. This did help thank you. Anyway about him talking about the DCEU and comics not working as well to debunk you need to remember he also used the comics to base most of his theory off of. Normally I really like MatPat's theories but this one was pretty of base.